# Typescript Generic 'Once' function

Tags: typescript

I am using a function from FP called Once(). As I am using TS I need to type it but can't work it out for this implementation. Here is my effort so far;

```
const once = <T, U>(fn: (arg: T) => U): () => U | undefined => {
let done = false;
return function(this: (args: T) => U) {
    return done ? void 0 : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, arguments));
};
```

}

I am using this for a method in a class:

```
class CSVOutput extends LogOutput {
private print_headers: (logStat: IStats) => void;
constructor() {
    super();
    this.print_headers = once((logStat: IStats) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(logStat).join(','));
    });
}
public print(logStat: IStats) {
    this.print_headers(logStat);
    console.log(Object.values(logStat).join(','));
}
```

}

my `tsconfig.json` looks like

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": ["node", "mocha"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
}
```

}

I get the TS warning `Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[T]'.`

How do I correctly write this function in typescript?

Comment: I think you might want to show us how you are calling `once`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `this`?  It looks like you're assuming that the function returned from `once()` will need to be called as a method of another function, which is... weird.  Do you care at all about methods?  Or are you trying to make `once()` accept only standalone functions where the `this` context is generally `undefined`?

Comment: It is not the calling that is the problem here. The compiler is complaining about the `arguments` in the `fn.apply(this, arguments)` because they are of type IArguments (this is built-in args array). So, to be clear, I am not introducing this `IArguments` param

Comment: @jcalz I have added the class I am using to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd change it to something like this:

```
const once = <A extends any[], R, T>(
  fn: (this: T, ...arg: A) => R
): ((this: T, ...arg: A) => R | undefined) => {
  let done = false;
  return function (this: T, ...args: A) {
    return done ? void 0 : ((done = true), fn.apply(this, args));
  };
};
```

Here we are accepting any function type, even methods where the `this` context is expected to be set.  Note that I'm consistently using [rest tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to represent the list of arguments.  The type of `arguments` isn't very strong in TypeScript, probably because for ES2015+ code you should be using rest parameters anyway.  Anyway, the return type of `once()` is a function with the same `this` context and parameter list as `fn`, and with the same return type or `undefined`.  This typing should mostly work for you, I think:

```
function yell(x: string) {
  return x.toUpperCase() + "!!!!!!!!!";
}

const yellOnce = once(yell);
// const yellOnce: (this: unknown, x: string) => string | undefined

console.log(yellOnce("hello")); // HELLO!!!!!!!!!;
console.log(yellOnce("goodbye")); undefined
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBOwFMYF4YB4CCMEA8oLABMIYBDMATwG0BdAGhgCUGAVAPgAoAoGGAMzAAuGBygALAJYRhLBgDoFpAE4BzYRgCUKNky4bhHUZOkxZMBXOVqYm7UxgAfGAFciCPhLAJCW5DoDePDAANgiwhOBIqHykwRAIANxBSmHOSmD8rsBQEuBGUjLyiqomtoG8vClQaRkRXjAA-DAAbiAShDAADDAGHHVRMFBKzggaDAKWAA6TwRT5EAxWEBoaSbwAvkmbXFx8WTngMBQIwcEcOMLQSp4qWuUwVTUwOHJQIACq0whKAMKk8RwtABqGAAIgAhJCoVDQVsdqBILBjqcAPJgRAoODohAcZHBVZcAD0hJgCOgRxOwTRiAM4gKLjAAGswCAAO5gBgXGBXG6+HQ8sAqRwMwjuTzeeHgCAgUJyYIgFS4ynUnGgsSUkCglYJGDEmAACQAogAZY0o6EWpJkmUIOUKpWo7EcUEqEAgQgAI2OWtWIrFXkIXCAA)